# Joomla group based access rights with multiple user roles

Tags: php, joomla-3.4, user, user-groups

I am finding this difficult situation and unable to give any proper solution.

A portal made on joomla has 3 types of users , 1 super admin , 2nd GroupLeader and 3rd GroupMember. A Groupleader can edit posts in specific category for which he was assigned as a group leader , group member cannot edit any thing but their own single profile pages.

Portal has different knowledge base categories like Food , Environment , Education etc. Which will have minimum one groupleader who will edit the internal pages of that category. But at the same time he can be a groupleader of other categories or a group member of any other category.

e.g. group leader XYZ is a leader of FOOD category so he can edit internal pages, group leader XYZ is also a leader of Education category so he can edit internal pages, Group XYZ is a group member of Environment category where group leader is another user called ABC.

Now the solution i have is very very long , i must create so many users access type based on category like Group_Leader_FOOD and GROUP_MEMBER_FOOD. So since i have around 20 groups i have to create 40 access rights which seems very very difficult to manage. Because the super admin will see the registered user and he supposed to choose whether to create one user as a group leader of multiple groups or just group member of multiple groups.

Can any one give easy way to manage this kind of issue? I am new in joomla and would love to see what experts have in mind to solve my issue.

Answer (score 1):

ACL is something very complex to understand, and if you do it wrong it can lock you out of your site...

I highly recommend that you purchase and install the popular ACL Manager from https://www.aclmanager.net/ as this will make your life a lot easier and simplify what is a very complex subject.

Joomla's built in ACL is very powerful, but not very well presented for beginners like yourself.

Remember - always take a backup before making sweeping changes (Highly recommend Akeeba Backup: https://www.akeebabackup.com/ - hopefully you are not so much of a beginner in Joomla to never have heard of this excellent backup extension.