# Restrict Publisher/Editor Access to Own Articles

Tags: joomla-3.x, permissions

In my Joomla website, I have a few departments like:

- Education
- Electricity
- Women Empowerment
- Tenders

Each department is handled by a different group of people. I will explain one scenario...

Tenders for each department is common.

In the Electricity department, there will be a tendor.

In the Education department there will be a tendor, but I need to create a "publisher account" who can access only their own articles.

I read some pages at Stackoverflow which will give access to specific categories, but not to their own articles.

In my case, the Education department may not access the Electricity department tenders or pages.

I created Education, Electricity, Tendors as one category in my Joomla.

How can I implement these permission requirements?

Comment: Have you looked at setting up User Groups for each department and giving just those groups access to the respective departments categories. Also under the permission for each group you can also set or deny access using 'Edit Own' which would restrict edit ability to only the person who is shown as the owner of the Article.

Comment: Sounds a bit like : https://stackoverflow.com/q/21134675/2943403 and probably 10 other links on JSE/Stackoverflow.

Comment: Perhaps this one too: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18920385/2943403 or https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/12440/12352